# Event error in Javascript

Tags: javascript, undefined

This code is not working for me:

Method call:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="botonRegistrar();">Guardar</button>
```

I have an object created, with this method:

```
this.Registrar2 = function(){
    this.boton.addEventListener("click",Registrar());
}
```

and that method call this function in the object:

```
function Registrar (e){

    self.contador = 0;

    if (self.nombre.value == "") {
        self.formgroup6_nombre.className = "form-group has-error";
    }else{
        self.formgroup6_nombre.className = "form-group has-success";
        aumentarContador();
    }

    if (self.apellido.value == "") {
        self.formgroup5_apellido.className = "form-group has-error";
    }else{
        self.formgroup5_apellido.className = "form-group has-success";
        aumentarContador();
    }

    if (self.usuario.value == "") {
        self.formgroup4_usuario.className = "form-group has-error";
    }else{
        self.formgroup4_usuario.className = "form-group has-success";
        aumentarContador();
    }

    if (self.password.value == "") {
        self.formgroup3_password.className = "form-group has-error";
    }else{
        self.formgroup3_password.className = "form-group has-success";
        aumentarContador();
    }

    if (self.email1.value == "") {
        self.formgroup_email1.className = "form-group has-error";
    }else{
        self.formgroup_email1.className = "form-group has-success";
        aumentarContador();
    }

    if (self.email2.value == "") {
        self.formgroup2_email2.className = "form-group has-error";
    }else{
        if (self.Iguales() == 0){
            self.formgroup2_email2.className = "form-group has-success";
            aumentarContador();
        }else{
            selfself.formgroup2_email2.className = "form-group has-error";
        }


    }
    self.botonguardar = 1;

    if (self.contador<6) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Oh, sorry, I forgot to paste this code.

```
var registro = new Registro();
registro.cargarFormulario("formularioRegistro");

function verificar(){
    registro.verificarMail();
}

function limpiarCampos(){
    registro.Limpiar();
}

function botonRegistrar(){
    registro.Registrar2();
}
```

here, I call registro.Registrar2().

but, mozilla tells me that e is undefined. So, the button send empty data. 
I've tried remove () in addEventListener, but nothing happens.
Anyone knows?

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: You have `onclick="botonRegistrar();"`. Can we see that function?

Comment: your method signature has an e, but you call it without any parameters

Comment: Why are you mixing `onclick` and `addEventListener` anyway?

Comment: I'm not sure but button type submit will submit your form and you're click event will be useless if you want to attach callback function attach it to form onsubmit event

Comment: I tried "submit" with the same result. I also tried to call the method with the parameter e, and the function didn't even executed. The button submit the data, with all the fields in blank

Answer (score 0):

As I see, clicking the button calls a undefined function "botonRegistrar();"

If you want to call function `Registrar` you should change your onclick action to this:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="Registrar(event);">Guardar</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making multiple calls, just add a event listener on your submit button. Try it on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/89wsLwmq/).

```
document.getElementById('guardarBoton').addEventListener('click', Registrar);

function Registrar(e){
   e.preventDefault(); // prevent the form from being submitted
   /* rest of your code here */
}
```

And your html:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="guardarBoton">Guardar</button>
```